# How can I implement the lollipop call animation in my application?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop, ripple

The animation that I'm talking about can be seen in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1BE0IftvT9c

At 0:18.

That Ripple effect comes from wherever it was called from. It's not only from that app, it may come from the contacts or the messaging app.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to check out [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Formatting your question correctly will go a long way to getting you the answer you are looking for.